# How to align parameters Textbox in SSRS 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have read in MSDN it says that...

1.Parameters pane:  The report viewer toolbar displays a prompt and default value for each parameter. Parameter layout on the toolbar is formatted automatically. The order is determined by the order that parameters appear in the Report Data pane.

It is not possible to change the design of the parameters textbox?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to change the design of the parameters textbox if you are using SSRS out of the box. If you want to customize the layout, you need to design a Web/Windows form and create your own layout for parameters and use the ReportViewer control to which you pass the parameters via code and then display the report.

Answer (score 0):

The below 'dirty' way worked for me. If you already have the parameters built then delete them and rebuild them
Step1: Create the paramters in the report data window in the order which you want them to be display left to right(and they overflow into the row below)
Step2: Assign the parameters in the same order in the dataset.